# Download Ubuntu with my Blackberry

Tags: smartphone

I don't know if thid question has been asked before.

I have a Pentium 4 desktop with Windows XP on it but I want to replace Windows with Ubuntu.

The computer can not boot from a USB device, and the CD ROM don't work at all.

The only way I can transfer software is to download it to my phone and then transfer it to my computer through the cellphone.

Can I download Ubuntu to my cellphone, and then copy it to my computer and install it drom the hard disk?

I want to completely replace the Windows on my Computer with Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you boot the Windows XP install at all?  And does it have Internet access?

Comment: I'd suggest you search on-line for your make and model of laptop with the word 'linux' or 'ubuntu'  to see if there is any user feedback/guides for your model.

Answer (score 0):

I still have Windows XP Professional on my PC. It has no Internet Access, and the CD is not working properly. I don't have a Windows CD. It was installed by the store where I bought it and they did not give me a CD. I can use my phone to install programs on my PC, but it can not boot from a USB.

Comment: You have answered your own question with the same question.  Please update your original question, or use the comments.